# Android Kotlin handling EditText change event

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

Here is a text box

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textBox"
    android:width="150px"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"/>
```

Here's some code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) // Unresolved reference activity_main

        val tb = findViewById(R.id.textBox) as EditText

        tb .addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Text changed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        })    }
}
```

The `findViewById` doesn't work because `Unresolved reference textBox`.

What's going on?
None of the examples I've found online work.
This is rubbish!
Why is Android development so exceptionally difficult?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add this back :   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

why ? `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutName)` is how you associate a layout file to an activity. think of it as connecting the xml you made in the layout to the activity. when you leave out the setContentView, your activity has no layout at all.

---

then, when it says it's unresolved, you have use the import:
`import your.package.name.R` (you can usually use alt+enter to bring up these types of suggestions for you)

just start typing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` then, there should be a line underneath the letter `R`, just click to the right of it and use alt+ enter to bring up suggestions for imports.

---

Additional info :

The `R` class is generated automatically from the application's resources, It contains the ids for the majority of resources created underneath the `res` folder

---

Entirely irrlevant note :

> Why is Android development so exceptionally difficult?

What's normal for the spider is chaos for the fly :)

Answer (score 1):

Please uncomment `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`from your activity. In kotlin you do not need to explicitly call findViewById. You can simply do this.

```
textBox.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "Text changed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
    })    }
```

Comment: I can't uncomment it because it doesn't work.

It turns out it is necessary to `import your.package.name.R`.